# except option not working in Router.onBeforeAction

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, iron-router

I have the follow code in my `routes.coffee` file, the `Router.onBeforeAction(...` function seems to be ignoring the `except` option and continually redirects to the 'sign-in' template. Why is this?

```
enforceLogin = ->
    if Meteor.userId() is undefined or Meteor.userId() is null
        isLoggedIn = false
        Router.go '/sign-in'
    else
        isLoggedIn = true
    return isLoggedIn

isCharacterNamed = ->
    userCharacter = Characters.findOne ownedBy: Meteor.userId()
    userCharacter.name is not undefined

checkCharacterNamed = (context) ->
    if !isCharacterNamed()
        Router.go 'create-character'

userCharactersSubscription = -> Meteor.subscribe 'userCharacters'

nonGameRoutes = ['sign-in', 'sign-up', 'sign-out', 'blog']

Router.map ->
    @route 'home', path: '/'
    @route 'adventures'

    @route 'create-character', onBeforeAction: ->
        enforceLogin()
        if @ready()
            if isCharacterNamed() then Router.go 'home'

    @route 'blog'
    @route 'admin/blog'

    @route 'loading'

    @route 'sign-in'
    @route 'sign-up'
    @route 'sign-out'

Router.onBeforeAction('loading')
Router.onBeforeAction enforceLogin, { except: nonGameRoutes }

Router.waitOn(userCharactersSubscription)

Router.onAfterAction ->
    if @ready()
        checkCharacterNamed()
        @render()
    else
        @render('loading')
,
    { except: _.union(nonGameRoutes, ['create-character']) }
```

Comment: similar issue here. I fall back by handling expects by myself in the `enforceLogin` function. it seems the except is not really working for me too. Maybe this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Router.onBeforeAction enforceLogin, except: nonGameRoutes

Comment: I will do tomorrow, but doesn't that compile to the same javascript?

Comment: Hmmm.. it just seemed weird, mixing js syntax with coffescript like this. But you are probably right and this is not the cause of the problem.
Do you have "loadingTemplate" defined for the onBeforeAction("loading") to fire up properly? Maybe this is causing the reload of the page. try to put some console.log in enforceLogin to be sure it's firing up.

Comment: Yes it is normal, braces and parentheses are optional. I did have the loading template defined, but it seems missing from the code there, I will check that out. The enforceLogin works because I have temporarily fixed the problem by putting it in each appropriate route.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work. I'm just wondering if that function is really the cause of the redirection. It might be just Meteor reloading the page caused by non existing route, for example. Do you see anything in console logs?